# How to return result of multiple cells into a fixed cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to make a times table chart to test my skills. I used conditional formatting to fill the cell with red color, if entered value is wrong `B2<>B$1*$A2` and with blue if entered value is right `(B2=B$1*$A2)`.**If I entered wrong value into any cell, I want the correct value is to be returned into a fixed cell.** Suppose [if I enter 0 in `B2` Cell , the correct value 1 (because 1x1 =1) should be returned to cell (`AI9`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtIJ1.jpg)  if I enter wrong value in any cell I want to see the right value instantly after entering wrong value and hitting enter cell (`AI9`). So far I am trying for 3 days but I couldn't figure it out, but I managed to do that for single cell with this formula.
 `=IF(B2<>B$1*$A2,B$1*$A2, "")`
But I have 900 cells . I also tried
`=IF(B2:AE31<>B$1:AE$1*$A2:$A31,B$1:AE$1*$A2:$A31, "")` in `AI9` cell without any success. It's kind of hard to do that for each cell manually.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: snapshot2]

[image: Snapshot1]

Comment: Conditional formatting cannot change the value for another cell. So, this cannot work. Furthermore, you want your result cell to change as an answer to the most recent cell value changed. So, if someone enters 0 into B2 and directly afterwards into C2 the value -1 then your result cell should (if I understand correctly) reflect only the incorrect value for C2. Hence, you'll have to make use of the `Worksheet_Change` event. Alternatively, I'd suggest to create a complete error report of all the incorrect values on the sheet.

Comment: thanks for your reply and suggestion @Ralph. how can i create a complete error report of all incorrect values on sheet please guide me . thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to write the appropriate VBA code for that and then the check can be run whenever someone presses a button to check all cells. This is how I'd do it: (1) copy all cells into a variable (array variable) in VBA and then (2) loop through the array to check each cell if the value is correct or not. (3) If an error is found then add a new sheet and start the error report (4) keeping track of all the errors using an error-counter variable (5) possibly with automatic (clickable) links on the new sheet to automatically redirect to the cell with the incorrect value. But that's just me.

Comment: thanks @Ralph could you please post code so that i can use . i don't have any idea of VBA

Comment: Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. If you don't know VBA then you can hire someone to do the job for you. Just search on the web for `VBA freelancers`.

Comment: sure thanks man . i will keep it in mind@Ralph

Comment: To get you started with VBA I recommend that you (in a first step) record the things you want Excel to do for you with the VBA macro recorder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_HQGHPBYoo Afterwards, have a look at the code and try to understand it by highlighting VBA key-words and pressing `F1`. Also, I'd recommend reading this: http://www.homeandlearn.org/ Afterwards you should be set to provide a first solution to the above problem yourself. If you're still having problems, feel free to come back here and ask for specific advice on something you have attempted to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how much you know about VBA but it sounds like your best answer.
Follow the following steps and it'll do what you're asking for above:

1. Open a new workbook
2. Rename you first sheet "Tables"
3. Press Alt and F11 simultaneously
4. This will open the VBA window - double click on the "Sheet1 (Tables)" icon on the left had side, as below - The large gray will turn to white, like mine:

[image]

5. Click anywhere on the large whit part and insert the below code:

> ```
> Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
>
> If Target.Row = 1 Or Target.Column = 1 Then Exit Sub
>
> If (Cells(1, Target.Column) * Cells(Target.Row, 1)) = Target.Value Then
>     With Target.Interior
>         .Pattern = xlSolid
>         .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
>         .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
>         .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
>         .PatternTintAndShade = 0
>     End With
>     Else
>         With Target.Interior
>             .Pattern = xlSolid
>             .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
>             .Color = 12632310
>             .TintAndShade = 0
>             .PatternTintAndShade = 0
>         End With
>         Application.EnableEvents = False
>         Range("AI9").Value = Cells(1, Target.Column) * Cells(Target.Row, 1)
>         Application.EnableEvents = True
> End If
>
>
> End Sub
> ```

6. Hit save (near the top-left) and close the VBA window
7. You tables should do what you want it to (and it you have multiple columns, it'll also work)

Note: If you want to change the cell where the correct answer gets put into (as apposed to AI9) just change that bit with the "AI9" in the bottom part of my code.

I've run this on my own excel and it works perfect

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thank you so much @Jeremy you are a pro . works like charm . could you give me code to analyze which tables i entered wrong while learning . It will be more helpful if you can tell me how to do it .I can learn faster . Thanks again Jeremy

Comment: I'm at work at the moment so can't but I'll post something up when I get home but if you just continue to fill out the worksheet above you could see them all across the your worksheet - I'll send on a screen shot later to explain what I mean

Comment: Ok, I'm back - The above code can be done for multiple Columns and rows (See below) - You can extra columns and rows to.

Comment: !PicturesScreen shot of excel table.PNG

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to ad a pic in the comments so I had to just add this picture as a new answer

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help @jeremy .  u'r the best :) _/\_